# Overriding console.error in a Create-react-app application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I have one Create-React-App (CRA) application and I would like to override console.error method because there are some errors from a third-party library that I do not want to see it.

I have tried this code with no luck:

```
const orig = console.error;
console.error = function() {
    var msgs = [];
    while(arguments.length) {
        msgs.push([].shift.call(arguments));
    }
    // From here I try to debug my new function without success.
    orig.apply(console, msgs);
};
```

Inspiration here: https://gist.github.com/pincheira/2724082

Suddenly I tried to sniff window.onload event, but I am not able to stop the propagation of this event when I want to stop it:

```
window.onerror = (msg, src, lineno, colno, error) => {
    // Not our business
    const nob = srcErrorMsgs.some((i) => src?.includes(i));
    if (nob) return undefined;
};
```

Of course, I run these functions from my index.ts.

I think CRA is doing some extra implementation because I have never had those kinds of problems in my life.

Comment: Isn't it easier to simply use the filter function of the DevTool?

Comment: No, It isn't @secan. We have to remove all 3rd party errors in order to avoid the client to see them.